# npm install not working after I update my dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have been following Google's angular tutorial and I've ran into troubles after [`step 7`](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07#dependencies).

I've updated my dependencies in `bower.json` like so (added "angular-route": "~1.4.0") :

```
{
  "name": "angular-phonecat",
  "description": "A starter project for AngularJS",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.4.x",
    "angular-mocks": "1.4.x",
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "~1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Here is what I type:

```
pavels@pavels:~/Desktop/angular-phonecat$ sudo npm install
```

And here is my error:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd angular-phonecat@0.0.0 bower install (wd=/home/pavels/Desktop/angular-phonecat)
```

I'm pretty new to front-end stuff like javascript frameworks such as `AngularJS`, what should I do to fix it? What I'm doing wrong?

Well, I have installed bower globally (by running `sudo npm install -g bower`)
and this is what I get when I'm trying to run `bower install` from the directory I'm working in:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:46
            throw err;
                  ^
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/pavels/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:500:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:352:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:20:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
at ensureInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:25:19)
at Object.setup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:41:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
```

Comment: show us your app tree, just want to see your file structure

Comment: Hm. That could take a while if I will post it as a text. Can I post it as an image? Or there is the way to export your app tree as a text?

Comment: you need to run bower install... if you dont have bower globally then run npm install -g bower first then run bower install

Comment: In this case `npm install` will trigger a `bower install`. Does the command `bower -v` (outputs the version) executes without error on your environment?

Comment: `pavels@pavels:~/Desktop/angular-phonecat$ npm -v
2.11.3
pavels@pavels:~/Desktop/angular-phonecat$ bower -v
1.5.3
pavels@pavels:~/Desktop/angular-phonecat$ nodejs -v
v0.12.7`


This is what I get when I type npm, nodejs and bower + '-v'

Answer (score 0):

it seems like npm cannot run in the working directory, try this

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm
```

if it still not working , try to add the following into your package.json

```
"config": {
    "unsafe-perm":true
}
```

3rd option is to change the owner of /usr/local/lib/node_modules to your user_name , then run npm insall without sudo.

```
chown -R your_user_name usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a directory permission issue. I'd recommend changing how you have node.js installed. [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is a great solution to this problem.  Be sure to uninstall all of your global packages (`npm ls -g -depth=0` followed by `npm uninstall -g <package>` for each one).  Then uninstall node and re-install it via nvm. That should fix all of your permission issues. You'll no longer need to use `sudo` when running `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `sudo npm install` therefore the *install script* is **executed as root**. The install script triggers a `bower install`, but bower does not allow to be executed as *root* (except with the `--allow-root` option but that is not the case).

The solution is to loose the habit to launch `npm` as root. You'll probably encounter `EACCESS` error permissions, because `npm` folders are at the moment owned by *root*. Follow [fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) first.

Then retry an `npm install`.